# Object type 'SandboxInfo' is not supported

Tags: rest-api, sandbox, tooling-api

When executing the following query I get the error message

> "Object type 'SandboxInfo' is not supported":

`/services/data/v38.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+SandboxInfo`

The current user is `"Administrator"` with `"View All Data"` activated and the current Org type is `"Sandbox"`. Any solutions?

Comment: Can you run the same in PROD org ? I fear you won't get any result  in sandbox org .

Comment: @MohithShrivastava you are right, please post this as the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The API is applicable only for PROD instance from where different sandboxes are spun.Hence it won't return any result for sandbox